# How to output kanji with furiga in the console with Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby

I know that you can add furigana to kanji in html by using the ruby HTML element:

```html
<ruby><rb>令和元年</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>れいわがんねん</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
```

Which looks like:

[image: furigana-output-in-html]

I was wondering if I could achieve similar output in the Ruby console?

```rb
>> "令和元年 れいわがんねん"
=> "令和元年 れいわがんねん"
```

Are there any existing gem or built in methods which would bring the furigana above the kanji?

Comment: AFIK, UTF has no special _furigana_ characters. You use just a smaller font in _hiragana_ for this purpose, but you can't have different font sizes in different lines in a text console. Even if it did, you would have to adjust the text sizes manually: For, say, 蚊, you need a single furigana (か), while for 車, you would need three (くるま).